# setInterval function not working in RxJs 6 +

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am learning RxJs. I've created an Observable that emits some values and for one value I tried putting a SetInterval(). But it is not emitting the values during that interval.
Is there any alternative function or Am I missing anything else.

Below is the code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { from,interval } from 'rxjs'


var observable = Observable.create(function subscribe(observer : any){
try{
   observer.next('Hey guys!')
   observer.next('How are yu ??')


     setInterval(()=>{
    observer.next('I m good')
   },3000)
   observer.complete();
   observer.next('After Complete')
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        observer.error(error)
    }
});


var timeObservable = interval(1000);
var timeSubscriber = timeObservable.subscribe((sec: any)=> 
{console.log(sec)});


var observer= observable.subscribe((x: any)=> addItem(x),
                    (error: any)=> addItem(error));

function addItem(val: any)
{
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(val);
    node.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: `But it is not emitting the values during that interval.` Of course not. `('I am good')` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Then how does it emit values at continuous interval

Comment: How about `observer.next('I am good')`?

Comment: Yes changed to  setInterval(()=>{
    observer.next('I m good')
   },3000) But din't work

Comment: @tkausl found the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I got the answer. By the time the code reached the setInterval with an interval timeout of 3000. The Observable reached complete() which doesn't emit values anymore. Instead I removed the complete() to continuously emit values. And added unscubscribe() to be triggered after 6001 milliseconds.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { from,interval } from 'rxjs'


var observable = Observable.create(function subscribe(observer : any){
try{
   observer.next('Hey guys!')
   observer.next('How are yu ??')

   setInterval(()=>{
    observer.next('I m good')
   },1000)
   }
    catch(error)
    {
        observer.error(error)
    }
});


// var timeObservable = interval(1000);
// var timeSubscriber = timeObservable.subscribe((sec: any)=> 
// {console.log(sec)});


var observer= observable.subscribe((x: any)=> addItem(x),
                    (error: any)=> addItem(error));

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        observer.unsubscribe()
                    },6001)

function addItem(val: any)
{
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(val);
    node.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(node);
}
```